# Complex CSS Shape

Tags: css, css-shapes

I need some CSS help. It’s hard to explain, but looking at the snippet I need the black part without the red.

I used two elements, but it should be possible with one...

```css
.q-rounder {
  background: #222;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
}

.quarter-circle {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 100px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 100px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="q-rounder">
  <div class="quarter-circle"></div>
</div>
```

([*fiddle*](https://jsfiddle.net/m6nwv45j/))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a radial gradient as background

```css
.q-rounder {
  background: 
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at bottom right,transparent 94%, #222);
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="q-rounder">
</div>
```

Another syntax with the `at` to have better support ([safari doesn't support the `at`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54299171/8620333))

```css
.q-rounder {
  background: 
    radial-gradient(farthest-side,transparent 94%, #222) top left/200% 200%;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="q-rounder">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use a solid background color, maybe this fits for you?

basicaly the before elements lays behind an rectangle which has border-radius an a solid background-color.

Supported in every browser and version.

```css
.q-rounder {
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 100px 0 0 0;
}

.q-rounder:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: black;
  content: "";
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="q-rounder">

</div>
```

Comment: it's almost the same as he already did, you simply changed the red with white. I think the idea is to have transparency

Comment: if transparency not needed, my approach has more browser support :D

Comment: more browser support than what? and if transparency is not need then the OP already have his code, no?

Comment: he asked for a solution with just one element