# How to correctly position a radial gradient background?

Tags: css, radial-gradients

I have small problem with css position with this code.

Unfortunately I need this circle to be on the right side of the page (div) and not in the middle. Thanks for the answers

```css
body{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 }
 
 .session-box{
 background:#333;
 width:100%;
 min-height:100vh;
 }
 
 .circle{
 position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left 0;    
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 background: -moz-radial-gradient(transparent 200px, rgba(255,255,255,0.6) 200px);
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(transparent 100px , rgba(255,255,255,0.6) 200px ) ;
  background: -ms-radial-gradient(transparent 100px, rgba(255,255,255,0.6) 200px);
  background: -o-radial-gradient(transparent 100px, rgba(255,255,255,0.6) 200px);
  }
```

```html
<div class="session-box">
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

i need this
[image]

Comment: With 'circle', do you mean 'circle' or 'ellipse'?

Comment: What you need is [gradient-position](https://www.quirksmode.org/css/images/position.html), [docs here](https://www.quirksmode.org/css/images/position.html).

Answer (score 2):

insert `circle at calc(100% - 200px)` as first parameter

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient or
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-radial-gradient/

```css
body{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 }
 
 .session-box{
 background:#333;
 width:100%;
 min-height:100vh;
 }
 
 .circle{
 position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left 0;    
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at calc(100% - 200px), transparent 100px, rgba(255,255,255,0.6) 200px);
  }
```

```html
<div class="session-box">
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another syntax in case you want better support than the `at` one ([Safari doesn't currently support the `at` syntax for `background`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54299171/8620333)). The gradient will by default be placed at the center so we increase the size of the background to move the center position to the right.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.session-box {
  background: #333;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* Circle with 100px Radius*/
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle 100px, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6) 100%);
  /* Twice bigger than the container minus 2xRadius */
  background-size: calc(200% - 200px) 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="session-box">
  <div class="circle">
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also do it without `calc()`:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.session-box {
  background: #333;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-right:100px; /*Equal to radius*/
  /* Circle with 100px Radius*/
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle 100px, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6) 100%);
  /* Twice bigger than the container */
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-origin:content-box; /* We don't consider the padding when doing the calculation */
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="session-box">
  <div class="circle">
  </div>
</div>
```