Why is only the top color of my gradient showing in Safari?
background: 
    radial-gradient(5% 10% at 40% 80%, rgb(255, 98, 0) 100%, #FFB81A00 100%),
    radial-gradient(30% 40% at 60% 40%, rgb(255,61,0) 74%, #FF3D0000 100%),
    radial-gradient(30% 70% at 40% 40%, rgb(254,0,255) 94%, #FFB81A00 100%),
    radial-gradient(20% 30% at 60% 40%, rgb(204,0,0) 94%, #FF3D0000 100%),
    radial-gradient(20% 50% at 20% 40%, rgb(37, 0, 89) 74%, #FFB81A00 100%);

This is my CSS for multiple radial gradients showing in my hero section. In Chrome this shows perfectly, but in Safari it only shows the first color. I've Googled it in many different ways but can't find a solution.
I tried to change the percentages of the gradient, I had 500% somewhere and figured it might cause problems. I Googled why Safari could only be showing the first color but couldn't find anything relevant to my problem.

related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54299171/8620333

It seems the Safari issue could be resolved by changing the way I positioned the gradients:
background:
-webkit-radial-gradient(30% 40%, 40% 40%, rgb(254,0,255) 30%, transparent),
-webkit-radial-gradient(60% 30%, 50% 50%, rgb(255,61,0) 50%, transparent),
-webkit-radial-gradient(50% 70%, 40% 40%, rgb(255,98,0) 100%, transparent);
However I ran into another issue which is that Firefox doesn't spread the gradients as much, and they look much more intense. How can I solve that?
